# Developer tools that map background Javascript to a symbol table?

Tags: javascript, developer-tools, symbol-table

I was looking in the Firefox dev tools (not firebug) and they do not appear to track background Javascript (such as code that is executed with `setInterval`). Are there any developer tools that would keep track of `setInterval` runs and when the next time it's going to be executed is?

Comment: `setInterval` does not execute in background, it runs in the main thread at regular intervals.

Comment: That might help you: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/

Answer (score 1):

Chrome provides tools to debug asynchronous javascript.

It is explained in details in this article: [Debugging Asynchronous JavaScript with Chrome DevTools](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/developertools/async-call-stack/)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? If you put a `debugger;` statement in the code with the dev tools open, will the debugger not break?

Comment: This should probably be posted as a comment, not an answer.